# Solving constrained optimization problem using PyTorch: Minimizing L1 norm of $\vec{x}$ subject to $\vec{x} = \mathbb{A^{-1}}\vec{y}$

Tags: algorithms, optimization, machine-learning, constraint-programming

My goal is to solve the above-constrained minimization problem where my vector to be optimized is `x`. The matrix `A` and the vector `y` are known to me. There are a lot of non-PyTorch libraries like CVXPY and scipy.minimize that do it, but they are very slow when the matrices become large and I am going to run this algorithm on a GPU for faster performance.

This is the code I am currently running:

```
x = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(num_pixels, 1, requires_grad=True).to(torch.float32).to(device))

optimizer = optim.Adam([x])

lamb = 5
# Optimization loop
for i in range(500):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = torch.norm(A@x-y, p=2) + lamb*torch.norm(x, p=1)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

x_solution = x.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is your question?  We are not a coding site, so requests for code or feedback on your code or questions about implementation are off-topic here.  Questions about algorithms and techniques are on-topic here.

Comment: I would delete and repost at Math SE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.